# How to use ros srv in different pkg

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/188982/message-headers-wont-build-first/
http://answers.ros.org/question/202312/how-to-use-srv-in-another-package/ (these answers didn't help me)

Here is the problem:

1. ros pkg `serial_interface` is providing the service `SerialWriteMsg.srv`. A test client inside this package can use the service.
2. ros pgk `conversions` wants to use this service. Here the CMakeLists.txt

   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
   project(conversions)

   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wno-write-strings -g ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

   find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
   message_generation
   serial_interface
   ackermann_msgs
   roscpp
   rospy
   std_msgs
   tf
   tf2
   tf2_ros
   )

   add_message_files(
   FILES
   SteeringMsgStamped.msg
   )

   generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
   )

   catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
   CATKIN_DEPENDS message_generation roscpp rospy std_msgs
   )

   include_directories(
   include
   ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
   )

   add_executable(velocity_conversion src/velocity_conversion.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(velocity_conversion ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
   add_dependencies(velocity_conversion serial_interface_generate_messages_cpp)
   ...

Here part of the package.xml

```
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>serial_interface</build_depend>
  <build_depend>ackermann_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>

  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>serial_interface</run_depend>
  <run_depend>ackermann_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_generation</run_depend>
```

Here is the srv file

```
Header header
uint8 type
int32 data
---
bool done
```

But this error occurs

```
catkin_ws/src/conversions/src/velocity_conversion.cpp:28:13: error: ‘struct serial_interface::SerialWriteMsg’ has no member named ‘header’
   serialMsg.header.frame_id = frame_id_;
```

Would you please help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238897/how-to-use-ros-srv-in-different-pkg/) by [sailor91](https://answers.ros.org/users/27405/sailor91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`serial_interface::SerialWriteMsg` is the service type, and includes both the request and the response.

Try using the request portion of the message instead:

```
serialMsg.request.header.frame_id = frame_id_;
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0